# Correlation Plot in R Won't Graph

Tags: r, regression, linear-regression, correlation, r-corrplot

DATA (hope this link works): https://www.dropbox.com/sh/eizrotzgdkssyx4/AABr_0PBJjaSXxooz3c0bSAZa?dl=0https://www.dropbox.com/sh/eizrotzgdkssyx4/AABr_0PBJjaSXxooz3c0bSAZa?dl=0

I am trying to analyze the various medical conditions (diabetes, asthma, highblood, etc) and their impact on readmission rates. Each column is for a different disease with a factor of either "Yes" or "No". I have to use multiple linear regression for the project. I recoded everything from Yes -> 1 and No -> 0 then changed all my columns to numeric. Now I am trying to do a correlation matrix and the actual matrix looks ok but when I go to plot it, nothing appears. Makes me think that I set up the data wrong.

```
medical_data <- read_csv("C:/Users/amand/Dropbox/School/D208 - Predictive/MLR_health_data_original/medical_clean.csv")

# Import file
medical_data <- data linked
# Create subset of data with just the medical conditions
conditions <- medical_data[27:38]
# Remove the "Complication_risk" column from the list of medical conditions since it does not qualify as a diagnosable disease under the purposes for this analysis
conditions <- conditions[-c(3)]
# Adds readmission column
conditions <- cbind(conditions, medical_data[20])

# Convert all variables from type "character" to type "factor" to convert later into numeric data
conditions[,colnames(conditions)] <- lapply(conditions[,colnames(conditions)] , factor)

# Convert factors to numeric
conditions[,colnames(conditions)] <- lapply(conditions[,colnames(conditions)] , as.numeric)

# Convert 1's to 0's
for (i in 1:12) {
conditions[i][conditions[i] == 1] <- 0
}

# Convert 2's to 1's
for (i in 1:12) {
  conditions[i][conditions[i] == 2] <- 1
}
```

When I use cor(conditions), I get very tiny values (-e05) for the columns Stroke and Reflux_esophagitis but everything looks okayish.

I tried using the Hmisc library using rcorr(as.matrix(conditions)) and I got the same values. I tried even making a heatmap and the values will not appear there either.

What am I doing wrong? Why are my values so small for only those two columns? Why can't I plot my correlation matrix?

Comment: The values in `conditions` are all zero or one. The low correlations mean that you cannot predict one condition from another - for example, know whether or not someone has high blood pressure gives very little help in predicting whether or not they have back pain. These conditions are largely unrelated.  Compare conditions with tests like `table(conditions[,1:2])`   This shows that (for this data) the incidence of stroke is the same whether or not the patient has high blood pressure. Your variables have no correlation so they show no correlation.

Comment: @G5W This is great to hear. I thought I was coding something wrong. I was able to get the corrplot working but like you said, everything only had a 0-0.3 correlation so the colors do not look right at all. Thank you so much.

Comment: I am glad to help.